# Using Null variables in conditions in T-Sql

Tags: t-sql, null

Is there a way to use a variable in the following manner?

```
DECLARE @ID int;
SET @ID = NULL;
SELECT *
FROM Market market
WHERE market.ID IS @ID
```

Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do

```
SELECT *
FROM Market market
WHERE market.ID = @ID OR (@ID IS NULL AND market.ID IS NULL)
```

Just for completeness at the moment it is still possible to do

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

SELECT *
FROM Market market
WHERE market.ID = @ID
```

but you shouldn't. This option is deprecated. [Quite an interesting related blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I was trying similar to the first answer, but without the @ID IS NULL and I got both values (when there is an int value and where it's null).

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason that you are trying to stick null into a variable rather than just doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM Market market
WHERE market.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to determine if market.ID is null, you would do this

```
SELECT *
FROM Market market
WHERE market.ID IS NULL
```

If you're testing to see if market.ID is null or some other value then try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Market market
WHERE market.ID IS NULL
  OR market.ID = @ID
```